# computing volume of unit ball in n-dimensions using polar coordinates

Tags: volume, spheres

Can one explain why the following formula holds for a n-dimensional ball volume?

[volume of n-dimensional ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxe46.png)

I can't seem to understand why we are integrating over $r^{d-1}$, and not $r^d$ for example.

Intuitively, I understand that we are doing a summation of the surface of a sphere with radius ranging from 0 to 1, thus receiving a ball.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: The $(n-1)$-dimensional volume element of the sphere of radius $r$ is $r^{n-1}$ times the volume element of the unit sphere. (Think about the formulas for $dA$ in polar coordinates and $dV$ in $3$-dimensional spherical coordinates.)

Comment: can you please elaborate? in the formula I have given there are no coordinates, what are the implicit variables I am missing?

Comment: Oh, $d\Omega$ is the volume element on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\Bbb R^n$. [Note how the two integral signs line up with the $dr\,d\Omega$.]